# If condition can be either true or false, why is it necessary

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

I'm super confused on this one. The code is to generate all permutations of a given list of integers. Once you do this, they add another constraint which is that the given input can have duplicates, and we want only unique permutations.

My code works...I'm just amazed at something I noticed. After looking over the code, I questioned whether a specific condition I had was necessary, so I negated it to see what would happen. The code still worked without flaw against 100 test cases. Essentially, this code works whether or not this condition is `true` or `false`.

So naturally, I thought I could just remove the condition, since it seems to be unnecessary. Long story short....the code now returns an empty result set. I'm hoping someone smarter than me can explain how this is possible because I am now questioning whether I belong in this profession.

The line of code in question is:

`if(seen[i] || (i > 0 && nums[i] == nums[i - 1] && !seen[i - 1]))`

Specifically `!seen[i - 1]` If you run this code as-is, it works. If you remove the negation and run it as `seen[i - 1]` it still works. If you delete `!seen[i - 1]` completely such that the condition looks like:

`if(seen[i] || (i > 0 && nums[i] == nums[i - 1]))` then the code returns the empty result set. I'm completely confused.

I'm using `[1,1,2]` as the input for the method and my expected result set is: `[[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[2,1,1]]`

```
class PermutationGenerator {
  List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

  public List<List<Integer>> permuteUnique(int[] nums) {
    if(nums == null || nums.length == 0){
        return result;
    }
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    backtrack(nums, new ArrayList<>(), new boolean[100]);
    return result;
   }

  private void backtrack(int[] nums, List<Integer> permutation, boolean[] seen){
    if(permutation.size() == nums.length){
        result.add(new ArrayList<>(permutation));
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        if(seen[i] || (i > 0 && nums[i] == nums[i - 1] && !seen[i - 1])){
            continue;
        }
        seen[i] = true;
        permutation.add(nums[i]);
        backtrack(nums, permutation, seen);
        seen[i] = false;
        permutation.remove(permutation.size() - 1);
    }
  }
}
```

My question is simply how is this possible? Code works if is true or false, but removing it completely does not work.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how it works, because you have `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`  when you try `seen[i - 1]` on first iteration

Comment: @Dred The condition also has `i > 0` so not sure how you're getting out of bounds exceptions.

Comment: @Patrick yes, I've tried a bunch of different arrangements of this conditional lol. Removing the `||` produces repeated permutations, which is what we want to avoid, so simply having the condition as `seen[i]` is insufficient. Also, if that were the case, the code would still work when removing the part in question, since the first part of the condition takes precedence. If the `seen[i]` was sufficient, the other part of the code would never get executed.

Comment: Yes, i deleted the comment because I misread the question, I'm not sure what's causing this to give the same result for the negation. Stepping through it with a debugger and looking at the values of i, nums[i] etc might be needed to understand what this condition is doing

Comment: @Patrick Ok.got it. Yeah, the negation still allowing it to work is one thing. But the code not giving correct result when that part of the code is removed does not seem logical, considering that the negation or removal of the negation gives the same result.

Comment: I ran the program with the changes you said, and all works fine I got the response of  . [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]] . ... when I passed {1,2,3} . for {1,1,2} the result is empty [] . because your condition ask it to continue for any matching case. same reply for all cases {1,2,2} or {1,2,1} or {2,2,1} ... your backtrack(nums, permutation, seen);  -- > always set the loop to continue.  and then permutation.remove() gets called.

Comment: @VinodSinghBist Ok. I'm following you. But consider if we add the condition back...it works whether it's true or false. If it continues for any matching case...then either `seen[i - 1]` or the negation of that should have different results; however both return identical result sets.

Comment: Im thinking it may be because `![seen]` filters out the first occurrence of the duplicates while `[seen]` filters out the next occurrences. So the results seem the same but the values are being taken from different parts of the array. Do any of your sets produce more than two duplicates?

Comment: @Dukeling Your example gives same number of iterations, but the result set if it were being stored would be different. Both would produces subsets of the same size, but the subsets would include numbers of the opposite parity or one another. This is to be expected. Same number of results, but the result set is different. In my case the actual result set is identical.

Comment: @Elron you are getting to the same result, but changing the seen[i-1] to !seen[i-1] actually changes the loop structure. where !seen[i-1] is more effective...

Comment: I suggest writing out and stepping through the program on paper, or with a debugger.  The negation seems like it's doing the same thing but it changes whether the duplicate is found in the recursive call or in the for loop I believe. Either way works but the condition is definitely needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that your code produces the same result with or without negating the last part of the condition and that it produces different results when the condition is removed.

This might seem like a miracle unless you consider that the whole condition is evaluated in a loop lots of times and it can well be that the three cases (with condition, with negated condition, without condition) all have different ways of processing and coming to the result.  What I'm trying to say is that with the condition and with the negated condition the same results are reached *but in different ways*.

This is the case here.  If you introduce some printf-debugging in the loop you will see that the result is reached in completely different ways.  The existing condition with negation lets the complete condition become true in other iterations than the condition without negation.  It is pure chance (without looking further at the algorithm) that in the end both lead to the same result.

Here is the execution trace of number `i`, the result of the complete condition, and the intermediate values of `nums`, `seen`, and `result` at this spot:

Without the condition:

```
0 F [1, 1, 2] [0, 0, 0] []
0 T [1, 1, 2] [True, 0, 0] []
1 T [1, 1, 2] [True, 0, 0] []
2 F [1, 1, 2] [True, 0, 0] []
0 T [1, 1, 2] [True, 0, True] []
1 T [1, 1, 2] [True, 0, True] []
2 T [1, 1, 2] [True, 0, True] []
1 T [1, 1, 2] [False, 0, False] []
2 F [1, 1, 2] [False, 0, False] []
0 F [1, 1, 2] [False, 0, True] []
0 T [1, 1, 2] [True, 0, True] []
1 T [1, 1, 2] [True, 0, True] []
2 T [1, 1, 2] [True, 0, True] []
1 T [1, 1, 2] [False, 0, True] []
2 T [1, 1, 2] [False, 0, True] []
```

With the condition `seen[i-1]`:

```
0 F [1, 1, 2] [0, 0, 0] []
0 T [1, 1, 2] [True, 0, 0] []
1 T [1, 1, 2] [True, 0, 0] []
2 F [1, 1, 2] [True, 0, 0] []
0 T [1, 1, 2] [True, 0, True] []
1 T [1, 1, 2] [True, 0, True] []
2 T [1, 1, 2] [True, 0, True] []
1 F [1, 1, 2] [False, 0, False] []
0 F [1, 1, 2] [False, True, False] []
0 T [1, 1, 2] [True, True, False] []
1 T [1, 1, 2] [True, True, False] []
2 F [1, 1, 2] [True, True, False] []
1 T [1, 1, 2] [False, True, False] [[1, 1, 2]]
2 F [1, 1, 2] [False, True, False] [[1, 1, 2]]
0 F [1, 1, 2] [False, True, True] [[1, 1, 2]]
1 T [1, 1, 2] [False, True, True] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
2 T [1, 1, 2] [False, True, True] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
2 F [1, 1, 2] [False, False, False] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
0 F [1, 1, 2] [False, False, True] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
0 T [1, 1, 2] [True, False, True] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
1 T [1, 1, 2] [True, False, True] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
2 T [1, 1, 2] [True, False, True] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
1 F [1, 1, 2] [False, False, True] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
0 F [1, 1, 2] [False, True, True] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
1 T [1, 1, 2] [False, True, True] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1]]
2 T [1, 1, 2] [False, True, True] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1]]
2 T [1, 1, 2] [False, False, True] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1]]
```

And with the negated condition `!seen[i-1]`:

```
0 F [1, 1, 2] [0, 0, 0] []
0 T [1, 1, 2] [True, 0, 0] []
1 F [1, 1, 2] [True, 0, 0] []
0 T [1, 1, 2] [True, True, 0] []
1 T [1, 1, 2] [True, True, 0] []
2 F [1, 1, 2] [True, True, 0] []
2 F [1, 1, 2] [True, False, False] [[1, 1, 2]]
0 T [1, 1, 2] [True, False, True] [[1, 1, 2]]
1 F [1, 1, 2] [True, False, True] [[1, 1, 2]]
2 T [1, 1, 2] [True, False, True] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
1 T [1, 1, 2] [False, False, False] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
2 F [1, 1, 2] [False, False, False] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
0 F [1, 1, 2] [False, False, True] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
0 T [1, 1, 2] [True, False, True] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
1 F [1, 1, 2] [True, False, True] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
2 T [1, 1, 2] [True, False, True] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1]]
1 T [1, 1, 2] [False, False, True] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1]]
2 T [1, 1, 2] [False, False, True] [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1]]
```

The execution steps are different in all three cases.  Two (by chance) have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the seen[i-1] or !seen[i -1], For the input types where 2 or more of the int array values are matching and fulfilling

```
  nums[i] == nums[i - 1]
```

The if condition gets TRUE and iterates over the int array, without adding.

and the "permutation.add" and "permutation.remove" are been called in sequence, for the first / last  element resulting in an empty set. sequence for the calls when tried with {1,1,2} OR {1,2,2} OR {1,2,1}

```
Add called
Add called
Remove called
Remove called
Add called
Add called
Remove called
Remove called
[]
```

for {2,2,2}

```
Add called
Remove called
[]
```

Code used:

```
       for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
            //System.out.println(seen[i]);
            if(seen[i] || (i > 0 && nums[i] == nums[i - 1])){
                //System.out.println("Inside if");
                continue;
            }
            seen[i] = true;
            System.out.println("Add called");
            permutation.add(nums[i]);
            backtrack(nums, permutation, seen);
            seen[i] = false;
            System.out.println("Remove called");
            permutation.remove(permutation.size() - 1);
        }
```